# make: *** No rule to make target `-lfl', needed by `count_words'. Stop

Tags: makefile

I am study Gnu make through book "Managing Projects with GNU Make".

I'm unlucky that I cannot even build pass first example on page: 5 of chapter 1.

OS: CentOS7

Here is code:

```
/* count_words.c */
#include <stdio.h>

extern int fee_count, fie_count, foe_count, fum_count;
extern int yylex(void);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    yylex();
    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", fee_count, fie_count, foe_count, fum_count);
    exit(0);
}
```

lexer.l

```
    int fee_count = 0;
    int fie_count = 0;
    int foe_count = 0;
    int fum_count = 0;
%%
fee  fee_count++;
fie  fie_count++;
foe  foe_count++;
fum  fum_count++;


#makefile
count_words: count_words.o lexer.o -lfl
    gcc count_words.o lexer.o -lfl -o count_words

count_words.o: count_words.c
    gcc -c count_words.c

lexer.o: lexer.c
    gcc -c lexer.c

lexer.c: lexer.l
    flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c

clean:
    rm *.o lexer.c
```

Build error is:

```
gcc -c count_words.c  
count_words.c: In function ‘main’:  
count_words.c:11:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]  
  exit(0);  
  ^  
flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c  
gcc -c lexer.c  
make: *** No rule to make target `-lfl', needed by `count_words'.  Stop.
```

When I remove -lfl from count_words prerequisites, it build with error too:

```
gcc -c count_words.c  
count_words.c: In function ‘main’:  
count_words.c:11:2: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘exit’ [enabled by default]  
  exit(0);  
  ^  
flex -t lexer.l > lexer.c  
gcc -c lexer.c  
gcc count_words.o lexer.o -lfl -o count_words  
/bin/ld: cannot find -lfl  
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status  
make: *** [count_words] Error 1
```

I have searched on web, but find nothing helpful.

Very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37971/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lfl

I try to install flex-static package, and the issue is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

You've forgotten to add

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

to the `count_words.c`

Comment: Thanks akond. Just now I fix it with following link. Thank you anyway.